# Why does my data still have missing value?

Tags: weka, missing-data

I am trying to split my data using Weka source code with traditional Java language. So I use this code to split from data which have missing value and the complete data.

```
public static void splitData(Instances data) throws Exception {
        withMiss = new Instances(data,data.numInstances());
        for(Instance datum : data) {
            if (datum.hasMissingValue()) {
                withMiss.add(datum);
                data.remove(datum);
            }
        }
    }
```

but when it is executed I still get this

```
Name                      Type  Nom  Int Real     Missing      Unique  Dist
 1 JK                         Nom 100%   0%   0%     0 /  0%     0 /  0%     2 
 2 Pendidikan                 Nom  98%   0%   0%     2 /  2%     5 /  4%    10
```

It shouldn't be happening, because I have removed all datum (or instances) which has missing value.

How can I fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesing case. Could you please try to replace the foreach-loop you are using with a regular for-loop starting from 0 going to data.numInstances()-1. Theoretically, it should not make a difference, but something must be wrong and this would be my first guess. Furthermore, try to plot data each time the remove() was called and see whether a change appears or not. By this we hopefully find the instances which cannot be removed.

Comment: I tried it, still the same.

Comment: When you run the for-loop, how many instances are being deleted? Is this number matching the truely deleted number of elements? We have to track down the problem. Is something which should be deleted not being deleted, or do we miss an etry completely, not even trying to delete it?

Comment: So after I try to locate which instances is instances no 74 and 102, in the console it says that those instances has missing value, and i have prove it with hasMissingValue method that return true. The problem is why they cannot be remove from data?

Comment: Please create an if-statement before data.remove() to check whether the running variable of your for-loop (I assume i) i==73. If this condition is true, check whether the .hasMissingValue for this instance is still true. If yes, see what happens after the data.remove() is called. plot the whole data or at least data.numInstances() before and after the .data.remove() step. I would expect that there should not be any change -> numinstances is identical before and after. If this is true, as a next step we have to investigate why data.remove() does not work for this particular 'empty' instance